# Why do I get "Unhandled Promise rejection: IDBIndex is not defined" Error when executing app-shell

Tags: node.js, angular, nrwl, angular13, app-shell

I get "IDBIndex is not defined" error when trying to serve the app-shell in angular nx application. I am able to serve the app without the app-shell, the app-shell was generated to an existing project using the nx console. Help me resolve this problem.
The error pops up after the following.

1. Browser application bundle generation complete
2. Copying assets complete.
3. Index html generation complete.

`Executing task: npx nx run vimbal:app-shell --configuration=development`

```
Generating application shell...Unhandled Promise rejection: IDBIndex is not defined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ReferenceError: IDBIndex is not defined
    at Module.2139 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:325780:38)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.37152 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:310888:61)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.9717 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:314189:81)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.90852 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:325635:81)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.63413 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:3732:80)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.52591 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:1432:71)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.39338 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:407:82)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.37618 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:43:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42) ReferenceError: IDBIndex is not defined
    at Module.2139 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:325780:38)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.37152 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:310888:61)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.9717 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:314189:81)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.90852 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:325635:81)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.63413 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:3732:80)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.52591 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:1432:71)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.39338 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:407:82)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
    at Module.37618 (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:43:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\chama\Documents\FYP\Application\vimbal\dist\vimbal\server\main.js:328113:42)       
✖ Application shell generation failed.
IDBIndex is not defined
```

```
Angular CLI: 13.8.1
Node: v16.14.0
Package Manager: npm 8.5.0
OS: Windows 11 Home
```

```
"@angular/animations": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.38",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^13.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~13.2.0",
    "@metamask/onboarding": "^1.0.1",
    "@ngrx/component-store": "~13.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "~13.0.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "~13.0.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "~13.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^13.0.2",
    "@nrwl/angular": "13.8.1",
    "firebase": "^9.4.0",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^13.0.0",
    "rxfire": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using firebase. my workaround was to lazy load components and avoided initializing service files I created in app.component.ts file.